# WP7 maximum application name length

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have to prepare names for application in different languages, the problem is sometimes name is too long and we cant find maximum length. Name of application visible on market is taken from xap file, so sometimes name on windows phone store is ok but in phone we can see only a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on a maximum number of characters in an application name if the constraint is that the entire name has to be visible on a phone since the size of the font used on the phone varies depending on the accessibility settings on the phone (you can make fonts larger throughout the phone for instance).

Comment: So to summarise I can make name of application longer than visible number of character on handset. There is no way to scroll name on handset. Looks like there is no way to prepare names that will be visible on all handsets